# Why I can't set transition for element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have mobile menu, when click on red  square, my mobile menu shows.

Problem is on right side where is image, there is problem with transition, because isn't applied to them, because left not accept transition, I tried using this for div
[fiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2719/)
THis also have problem with animation on image, check them

```
left:0px,
margin-left:250px;
```

but not working correctly on small phones like Iphone 4 ... 
[fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2718/)

```js
$("#show-mobile-navigation").on('click', function() {
    $('.glavni-kontejner').toggleClass("show-mob-nav");
    $('#mobile-navigation').toggleClass("show-mob-nav2");
});
```

```css
.glavni-kontejner {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#show-mobile-navigation {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ea1111;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999999999999;
}
#show-mobile-navigation i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
#mobile-navigation {
  margin-top: 151px;
  border-right: 3px solid #dc3128;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #dc3128 !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 9999999999999;
  padding-bottom: 140px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#mobile-navigation ul {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#mobile-navigation li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#mobile-navigation ul li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
#mobile-navigation li a {
  font-family: Bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.show-mob-nav {
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.show-mob-nav #show-mobile-navigation {
  left: 250px !important;
}
.show-mob-nav #mobile-navigation {
  left: 250px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
.show-mob-nav2 {
  left: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="show-mobile-navigation" class="container-fluid nopadding">
  <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div id="mobile-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="veleprodaja.php"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="maloprodaja.php"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="igraonica.php"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="servis.php"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="brendovi.php"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="firma.php"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="lokacija.php"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.php"> Lorem </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="glavni-kontejner">
  <<img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use :
$('.glavni-kontejner').animate(...) for this purpose.

Have a look to documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Because toggling classes is instantaneous, not a transition.

Comment: There is no need to use animate since all browsers support css transition now. Also it is wrong that toggling classes is instantaneous while using transitions @Bommox

Comment: I haven't said that toggling classes is instantaneous... but actually it is. Which is noy is the transition itself, but the js code runs  without waiting the effect to complete.

With jQuery you can achieve the same effect with a lot less CSS code (and no vendor prefixes worries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transition an element needs a default value and the end value.

you have the end value set in

```
.show-mob-nav {
  left: 250px;
```

so your container also needs a starting value

```
.glavni-kontejner {
    left:0;
```

The above code is fron your jsfiddle. With margin it would be the same

```
.show-mob-nav {
    margin-left: 250px;
}
.glavni-kontejner {
    margin-left:0;
}
```